# ZF3: $request->getQuery('my_var') vs $this->params()->fromQuery('var_name')?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3

I'm learning ZF3 from this [book](https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/using-zend-framework-3-book/html/en/toc.html), and I came across this:

In my controller, I can get the $_GET['var_name'] in ZF3 like this:

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$request->getQuery('var_name');
```

Or this way:

```
$this->params()->fromQuery('var_name');
```

What's the difference between the two? (Rephrasing the question: why there are 2 ways to do the same thing?). Is one preferred over another in specific scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data is part of the request, so that's why it's held in the request object. The params controller plugin (your second example) provides a more concise way to access this data, so that's what you should use to access the data from a controller.

Comment: In my first code example, is there other places where I can use this aside from controllers?

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->params()->fromQuery('var_name');
```

here `$this->params()` is controller plugin, you can only use it from controller.

but for

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$request->getQuery('var_name');
```

You can access requests from any class, as below-

```
$request = new Request();
```

Comment: To access request from any class, you should inject it using `ServiceManager`: `$container->get('Request')`.